# Tessract (tessnet2 for .NET) - more than 2 decimal places

Tags: .net, ocr, tesseract, tessnet2

I am strugling with a problem of reading data from a table.
If a number has got up to 2 decimal places everything looks OK, when number has got 3 decimal places I am not getting decimal point, ie. (instead of getting 5.575 I am getting 5575).

!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDgRg.png)

I have also tried tesseract 3.02 from https://github.com/charlesw/tesseract but I found this less reliable in reading data from source I want to read, that is why I am using old tessnet2.

I am using following white char list:
ocr.SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ.,");

and language pack: english for version 2up.

Do you have any advices what can I modify in order to get more accurate values?

Thanks,
Jack

Answer (score 0):

Try `bazaar` or [user-patterns](https://tesseract-ocr.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/tesseract.1.html) in Tesseract 3.0x.

Comment: Thanks, bazaar is not a good option for me. As a solution to my problem I've found work around (deviation of the numbers from a reliable source canonot be greater that 0.3% so I can put some logic around numbers from tesseract). thanks for suggestion.